# Can I use silicone lubricant on oven door hinges?

Tags: hinges

After using my self-cleaning cycle on my oven, the door hinges squeak. What is safe to use to stop the squeak? I have used olive oil, but it does not last.

Comment: I'd use powdered graphite or a product like lock-ese that is graphite in an alcohol base in an spray can

Comment: Silicone is typically good for something like 400 degrees. Your door hinges should never come remotely close to that.

Comment: I like tysons answer heat won't degrade the graphite and it won't outgas over time, my self cleaning ovens the hinges are inside and exposed so they will get hot.+

Answer (score 1):

[Sprayon](https://web.archive.org/web/20170705185701/https://www.sprayon.com/product-categories/industrial-lubricants/food-grade-high-temperature-lubricant-aerosol-lu213) has a food grade lubricant that should function for what you need.

Listing for this particular brand start around [$11](http://www.toolup.com/Sprayon-LU213-Food-Grade-High-Temperature-Lubricant) for a can

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this Molykote Product.

[Molykote® D-708 AF Coating](https://web.archive.org/web/20170710190650/https://www.dowcorning.com/applications/search/default.aspx?R=742EN)

It is used for oven door hinges and so it will resist the high temperatures.

For those that have issues with this Lubricant and would like a Lubricant used by frigidaire :

Notice this is high temp lubricant #930-AA
http://www.appliancepartspros.com/frigidaire-lubricant-high-temp-5303307893-ap2147006.html

Which you can see here:
https://www.lubriplate.com/Products/Multi-Purpose-Greases/930-Series.html

Comment: Strongly recommend against using that, according to the [MSDS](http://www.ulbrich-group.com/chemical-technical-products/MSDS_MOLYKOTE_D_708_eng.pdf) it is flammable and highly toxic around food.

Comment: @spade read the manufacturers directions and check the parts list. You will find it is what is used for oven hinges from the manufacturers site http://www.dowcorning.com/content/appliance/appliancehome/Ovens.asp
There are oven manufacturers that use it as well. However the op can buy new hinges to solve the problem.

Comment: the manufacturer explicitly stated it is intended for industrial usage, in an industrial setting, and that it was not evaluated for consumer usage. They actually refer to an outside agency for consumer usage, which then references particulate values the manufacturer does not make available. The recommended protective gear is far beyond what is readily available outside of commercial/industrial settings.

Comment: Is someone making the argument that a corporation has the health and best interests of consumers in mind? I have a bridge you may be interested in....

Comment: @TimNevins The argument is this: The manufacturer recommends product x. That is the Manufacturers recommended product. Another Option is to use the MolyKote D-708 AF coating. The manufacturer has at least performed some testing to determine what is considered safe. Consideration for safety is a risk analysis like the coatings on the inside of the oven, also have a risk analysis. If someone has an issue with the product then they will need to perform their own risk analysis (perhaps based in a million person study with medical tracking) or just a guess of what might be considered safe.

Answer (score 0):

Two of our high-rep regulars suggest graphite powder.